# cURL PUT Requests hangs

Tags: php, ssl, curl, wamp, freeze

So here's my problem.

I'm using curl to access my CouchDB by HTTP. I recently updated my WAMP to the WAMP 3 64bit wich comes with PHP 5.6.16 and Apache 2.4.17. Therefore, since this upgrade, I discovered that I couldn't do PUT request anymore.

## Env

1. PHP 5.6.16
2. Apache 2.4.17
3. Windows 10 64 bit
4. Wamp 3 64 bit

## Curl --version

```
 curl 7.49.1 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.49.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2h nghttp2/1.11.1
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL HTTP2
```

## Code executed

So when I execute this :

```
<?php
$table="testname";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:5984/' . $table);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'validUser:validPass');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
 'Content-type: application/json',
 'Accept: */*'
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

I get a quick response from the server.

Then, I try to create a database :

```
<?php
$table = "testname";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:5984/' . $table);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'validUser:validPass');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
 'Content-type: application/json',
 'Accept: */*'
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

## Problem

So, when I execute this code, the request will hang on curl_exec. 
What's weird is that, after the timeout, the request will be received by CouchDB but no response will be given. It seems that my "Put" request are stacked in a buffer and they are waiting to be executed.

**Verbose curl output**

```
* Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
*   Trying ::1...
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5984 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'validUser'
> PUT /customers HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5984
Authorization: Basic dGVzdEFkbWluOnRlc3RQYXNzd29yZA==
Content-type: application/json
Accept: */*

* Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
* Closing connection 0
```

## Hints

-I try to install a SSL certificate but It didn't seem to work. Having this certificate still installed can cause problems?
-I can do PUT request with a REST client on my Atom editor without problems. 
-I seems like there is a problem in my network route internally. I'm saying this because It affected the PHP-Curl aswell as the Curl CLI. Also, I'm able to do GET request but the PUT request are like "hanging" for no reason and are "Accepted" by my CouchDB when the timeout occurs. It's like if I was sending long poll request.

## What have been tested

1. Execute the same command on the command line -> Same result
2. Try a REST Client on my Atom editor with success
3. A friend of mine try to access to my database remotly with success (So CouchDB doesn't seem  the problem)

Comment: If you try `curl -X PUT http://127.0.0.1:5984/database_name` from the command line, does it work as expected?

Comment: @drew010 Yep, it does hang aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if I tested with my Firewall disabled, uninstalling my antivirus ( Bitdefender Total Security 2016) fixed my issue.